# Iptables -mac adress accept with a loop

Tags: bash, loops, iptables, mac-address

I'm trying to make an iptables rules in order to accept just some mac address. To do that, first, i make a get request to the endpoint api in order to get a mac adresss and I store the mac adress in a array.

Example:

```
declare -a MAC_ADDRESS=()

MAC_ADDRESS+=($(curl -sb "Application: accept/json" "https://myurl/endpoint_api"))
```

#(It is not really correct, but my get request is really working).

Then I make a loop to apply an iptable rules for all the items which are stored in my array, something like that:

```
for element in $MAC_ADDRESS
do
iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s7 -p tcp --dport 8080 -m --mac-source ${element} -j ACCEPT

done
```

And this is not working.. I don-'t know why.

I just want to apply this rule (and many other) to all the item in my array but this way it is not working, do you have any idea if it's possible and how?

Thank you vey much
Mo

Comment: Re-read a bash arrays introduction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49501157/using-the-array-name-without-an-index-gets-the-first-array-element-in-bash-ok

Comment: I dont'think this is a duplicate question since i'm trying to have a rules for all the elements sotred in my array. This is different from the other question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TIL bash does arrays! This is helpful.

https://opensource.com/article/18/5/you-dont-know-bash-intro-bash-arrays

It looks like the syntax you are using to call the array item is incorrect. To call the array elements you need to use ${ARRAY_NAME[@]}.

```
for element in ${MAC_ADDRESS[@]}; do 
    iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s7 -p tcp --dport 8080 -m --mac-source ${element} -j ACCEPT
done
```

I didn't have a JSON handy to test, so I just used an analog on my own HTP host with a flat file.

```
$ cat test1.sh
#!/bin/bash
unset LIST
declare -a LIST=( $( curl -s http://www.someurl.tld/z0th/file ) )
for item in ${LIST[@]} ; do
        echo "some text" ${item} "more text"
done
```

When you run that;

```
$ sh test1.sh
some text one more text
some text two more text
some text three more text
some text four more text
some text five more text
```

I tested the array by doing;

```
$ echo $LIST
$ echo -e "${LIST[@]} \n"
```

The first echo command, if an array, will output the first element only. The second will hand back the entire array. Replace the @ with an element number to call it specifically.